# Extracting specific text strings from a cell

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

Please take a look at the below text:

**Mr. Manimaran R MMTFD NL20824448862,Room no-206**

I have around half a million cells like this and i want to extract the ID number from this text using a formula. The problem that i am facing is that some ids start with NL some with NH and some with IN/IWA and the length of the text string containing the ids is also different (13/14/15 etc).
Is there any formula through which i can extract these ids??

Currently I am using this formula =MID(text,FIND("NH",text,1),15).
But i need to change it everytime for NL/IN as also for 14/15 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use of [external tools](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3639-excel-extract-part-of-string.html) is the way to go with that much variance in what you need to extract.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following (assuming text is in cell C3 (basically pivoting off the comma and looking back)

`=right(mid(C3, find(",",C3)-16,16),len(mid(C3, find(",",C3)-16,16))-find(" ",mid(C3, find(",",C3)-16,16)))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas with python3 to easily and quickly do such task.

In python3 shell

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.read_excel('./your_excel_file.xlsx') ##import from excel
df['ID']=df['Data_header_name'].str.split(' ',expand=True)[4].str.split(',',expand=True)[0] ##here you can use any relevant filters to get what you want
df.to_excel('output_excel.xlsx') ## save to excel
```

You also need to install openpyxl, xlrd, numpy, pandas using pip

```
pip install openpyxl xlrd numpy pandas
```